# In what short story was the character "Dril" used? OTR radio play?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, radio-play

"The Whispers" a new ABC scifi is using a storyline from an old Bradbury/Asimov short story about children and an "imaginary" friend called Dril.  Can you tell me the name of the short story and who wrote it.  I have gone through all of my OTR scifi programs and cant find it.  It bothers me that they didn't give credit to the original author.

Answer (score 10):

["Zero Hour"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40764) by [Ray Bradbury](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?194). The Wikipedia Page for [*The Whispers*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Whispers_(TV_series)) says, not quite accurately:

> It is based on the 1951 Ray Bradbury short story "Zero Hour" from *The Illustrated Man*.

Actually, "Zero Hour" was first published in the [Fall 1947 *Planet Stories*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?59991+c) (available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Planet_Stories_v03n08_1947-Fall#page/n41/mode/2up)); reprinted in a 1948 issue of [*Avon Fantasy Reader*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?57837) (also available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Avon_Fantasy_Reader_08_1948_Wolfhound#page/n67/mode/2up)), in the 1949 anthologies [*Invasion from Mars: Interplanetary Stories*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?18494) and [*My Best Science Fiction Story*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?308937), and in Bradbury's 1951 collection [*The Illustrated Man*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?41951); and dramatized as episode 26 (November 23, 1955) of the radio program [*X Minus one*](https://archive.org/details/OTRR_X_Minus_One_Singles/XMinusOne55-11-23026ZeroHour.mp3). A [TV adaptation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spIVwo6DAIE) was aired on January 10, 1992, as episode 5.2 of [*The Ray Bradbury Theater*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ray_Bradbury_Theater_episodes).

The name is spelled "Drill" with two l's:

> Mink banged away at the soup.
>
> "Slow down," said Mom.
>
> "Can't," said Mink. "Drill's waiting for me."
>
> "Who's Drill? What a peculiar name," said Mom.
>
> "You don't know him," said Mink.
>
> "A new boy in the neighborhood?" asked Mom.
>
> "He's new all right," said Mink. She started on her second bowl.
>
> "Which one is Drill?" asked Mom.
>
> "He's around," said Mink evasively. "You'll make fun. Everybody pokes fun. Gee, Darn."
>
> "Is Drill shy?"
>
> "Yes. No. In a way. Gosh, Mom, I got to run if we want to have the Invasion!"
>
> "Who's invading what?"
>
> "Martians invading Earth—well, not exactly Martians. They're—I don't know. From up. She pointed with her spoon.
>
> "And *inside*," said Mom, touching Mink's feverish brow.
>
> "You're laughing! You'll kill Drill and *every*body."
>
> "I didn't mean to," said Mom. "Drill's a Martian?"
>
> "No. He's—well—maybe from Jupiter or Saturn or Venus. Anyway, he's had a hard time."
>
> "I imagine." Mrs. Morris hid her mouth behind her hand.
>
> "They couldn't figure a way to attack Earth."
>
> "We're impregnable," said Mom in mock-seriousness.
>
> "That's the word Drill used! Impreg— That was the word, Mom."
>
> "My, my. Drill's a brilliant little boy. Two-bit words."
>
> "They couldn't figure a way to attack, Mom. Drill says—he says in order to make a good fight you got to have a new way of surprising people. That way you win. And he says also you got to have help from your enemy."
>
> "A fifth column," said Mom.
>
> "Yeah. That's what Drill said. And they couldn't figure a way to surprise Earth or get help."
>
> "No wonder. We're pretty darn strong," laughed Mom, cleaning up. Mink sat there, staring at the table, seeing what she was talking about.
>
> "Until one day," whispered Mink melodramatically, "they thought of children!"

Comment: Thank you so much.  I passed right over it as I was upset that the network had not given an author his due. One of his more enjoyable and one that I have taught to classes in years past but had a brain fart.  Thanks, again!

Comment: You're welcome. If you wish to do so, you can "accept" the answer by clicking on the check mark.